# Can I remove the public IP on my instance without terminating it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several instances on a vpc that communicate with each other through their private ips. Each instance was launched sometime ago and assigned a random public IP which is not used for anything. Since anything that is public presents a vulnerability and they are not used at all, I would like to removed them.

Is it possible to Remove public Ip Addresses without terminating the instance?

Comment: If you are running Linux block all outgoing and incoming connections on the public IP using Iptables, if you are on  Windows do it with the Windows firewall

Comment: Nothing would reach to your server. Just use security groups, they are kind of firewall rules.

Comment: That is simply unmaintainable,.. You would have to check the iptables or firewall everytime you want to verify the public IP is not in use?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nope that is not possible without terminating the instance. If it was Elastic Ip then it would have worked.

The only option is Take AMI of the instance, terminate the instance and launch the AMI in the VPC without enabling Public Ip address for that instance.

Once you terminate the instance with that private IP you can assign that private ip again to a new Instance you created from the Image. (As long as it's in the same VPC and subnet) This way you don't need to update the private IPs off all the "instances on a vpc that communicate with each other through their private ips"

Comment: so would a simple reboot, where the Public IP is released anyway, not work?

Comment: In AWS simple reboot will not change the IP you have to start and stop the instance

Comment: It is possible, please note CyclingDave's comment.

Answer (score 43):

Yes you can remove a public IP address from an instance.

This solution applies when your instance was launched in a subnet with the "auto-assign public IP" setting enabled.
This makes AWS add a public IP address that seems hard to remove.

Notes:

- If you change the subnet auto-assign setting and stop and start the instance,
  this does not work, it has no effect. The public IP remains.
- If you got your public IP by associating an elastic IP then it's
  a different case and easy to fix; all you need to do is right-click on 
  the instance or on the Elastic IP, and choose "Networking", "Disassociate 
  Elastic IP Address")

There is a voted-down solution here that seems to work at first, but the public IP comes back (as a different address) when you start the instance up again.

Solution: (detailed steps below)

You need to first add another Network Interface, (so there are two or more N.Is), then you can release the public address by adding and removing an 
elastic IP.

Here is a detailed step-by-step guide:

1. Create a new network interface.
2. Attach the new network interface to your instance. Now there will be two 
   or more network interfaces attached to your instance. This is important.
   There MUST be two or more for this to work.
3. Create a new Elastic IP (in the EC2 console).
4. Right-click on the new EIP and associate it to the instance whose public IP
   you want to remove. The original public IP will be replaced by the new one.
5. Now do the reverse of step 4, disassociate the EIP you have just added. 
   At this point, right-click on the instance and select "Networking", "Manage
   IP addresses", you will see there are no public IPs on you instance any 
   more. at this point. You must refresh the instances view otherwise you
   will not see this.

   The public IP is now gone for good. 
   Even if you stop and start the instance, it will not return.
6. Tidy up: delete the elastic IP you created earlier. Don't delete the new 
   extra Network Interface. This has to stay in place. If you remove the new / 
   second NI then the public IP will come back the next time you stop and 
   start the instance.

I know this sounds a bit strange, but it is in the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html) and I've tested it and it works.

The relevant part from the AWS documentation on that page, is this: "If the public IP address of your instance in a VPC has been released, it will not receive a new one if there is more than one network interface attached to your instance."

Comment: Make sure that 1. your subnet auto-assign setting is set to _not_ allocate a public IP, 2. follow the steps above exactly, especially point 6; do not delete the new interface you just added, there must always be two or more. They must remain to keep the public IP away.  If you have only one, it will come back when you restart. , 3. when looking at the instance to test it worked, be sure to refresh the page. 4. if you still have issues, contact AWS tech support, referencing the link above from the AWS documentation which describes how this works.

Comment: This very weird workaround works, but I had to stop and restart the instance. Thank you!

Comment: All right, I'm coming back to let you know that this solution basically destroyed my network. My services were completely unable to reach the internet. I had to rollback the changes. I'm not a network expert so I can't tell you whether this is related to misconfiguration on my part, but I followed the steps above carefully. I think the issue may be related to this doc: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-secondary-network-interface/

Personally, I'm going to keep the public IP and configure my security groups to disable inbound internet traffic instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "basically destroyed my network", if you lost connectivity to the internet, yes that's what this procedure is meant to do. These are steps meant to remove the public (internet-facing) IP, that's the goal.

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of freaking out in that last comment. The goal was for EC2 instances not to be accessible by the internet, and have all traffic be safely routed through the load balancer. This is already what happened previously through the usage of security groups, but I wanted to remove the EC2 IP for hardening compliance reasons. There must be something I did not understand, because I believe the main issue was that the EC2 instances could not reach the internet, which I expected should happen via the load balancer. Maybe this is what I misunderstood.

Comment: I came across this issue and solution while spinning up some new instances.  If you're on the fence about just building a new image and you haven't gotten too deep yet, just terminate and build fresh - you can even create a new instance with almost the same config by going to Actions > Image and templates > Launch more like this, then apply the same config minus the public IP.  I'd only do the multi-network interface hack if there was absolutely no way to create a new instance, it's definitely a kludge.

Comment: in fact your solution fails already on step 4 https://imgur.com/kbaSpRn, the EIP cannot be associated to the instance with two active ENIs

Answer (score 5):

Steps worked for me:

1. Disable auto assign public IP setting on vpc subnet.
2. Stop the ec2 instance.
3. Open Network Interface Manage IP address settings and assign a secondary private IP.
4. Open Elastic IPs and associate an elastic IP to the ec2 with secondary private IP.
5. Start the Ec2 Instace.
6. Open Network Interface Manage IP address settings and unassign the secondary IP.
7. Done, now you can release the previously associated elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked

```
create temp-priv-ni same subnet private interface use default security group
eni-xx-temp-priv-ni 
allocate new public elastic ip
associate new public elastic ip to instance 
attach eni-xx-temp-priv-ni to same instance

check instance has two private ips and new public elastic ip and past public eip is gone
then 
disassociate public eip 
go to instance network interfaces and detach eni-xx-temp-priv-ni
server will be now with same private ip and its public ip gone 

the new public ip and new private ips can be deleted
```

Answer (score -3):

It is a very old thread but the easiest way of removing a public ip associated via VPC settings is:

1. create an elastic IP
2. assign the elastic ip to the host owning
   the public ip that you want to release (the ip is released at this
   step)
3. disassociate the ip address from the elasic ip management
   screen.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. When I disassociate the IP from the Elastic IP management console, somehow a new public IPv4 automatically gets generated and attached to the EC2 host.

Comment: Can confirm, just tried and it does not work, you just get a new random public IP.